# Are the non async versions of CloudBlockBlob uploads deprecated

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I may be doing something very obviously wrong here. I'm looking for `UploadFromStream()`, `UploadFromFile()` in `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`. I can only find `UploadFromStreamAsync()` and `UploadFromFileAsync()`.

*From comment:* I am using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage Version 6.2.0. I'm trying to build Windows IoT Core Universal app. Quite simply I'm trying to upload an image from a Raspberry Pi to Azure.

Comment: Where are you using this `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` library? Are you trying to build Windows 8/10 applications? Also, please tell us the version of the library you're using.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. I am using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage Version 6.2.0. I'm trying to build Windows IoT Core Universal app. Quite simply I'm trying to upload an image from a Raspberry Pi to Azure.

Comment: @user2374309 In the future, when adding additional detail, edit your question; don't bury details in comments. I already edited your question to include the details from your comment (so you can delete your comment at this point).

Answer (score 2):

Our Universal library uses an async paradigm, so you'll have to use the async APIs. This is as intended -- is there a problem you have with the Async methods?

The sync methods are for .NET 4.0+ (the desktop targets).